# How to flash non Debian system to BeagleBoardBlack from microSD?

Tags: beagleboneblack

I built a Linux system with Buildroot for my BeagleBoneBlack.
It boots well from the microSD.

How can I copy the whole microSD content (boot and rootfs) to the eMMC?

Answer (score 0):

You *should* be able to just `dd` to the eMMC (usually appearing as `/dev/mmcblk0` when booted from SD).

It might make more sense to adapt the [eMMC flashing script](https://github.com/RobertCNelson/boot-scripts/tree/master/tools/eMMC) used by the Debian images though.

Answer (score 0):

you can see here [link](http://www.armhf.com/boards/beaglebone-black/bbb-sd-install/). a article guide how to create a sdcard boot kernel linux!!